# iPad: Event handler for "Next"/"Enter" key?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield

How do you catch the "Enter" key event on a UITextFIeld on the iPad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the `-textFieldShouldReturn:` delegate method, declared in the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. To make an object the delegate of the text field, set the field's `delegate` property to that object.

Comment: Good discussion with sample code here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=462104